# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed (Laravel Migration)

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-migrations

As written in the error logs, maybe the error is caused different forms in the reference table and parent table but I still don't understand cause I'm new in programming

here table 1

```
<?php

Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('question');
    $table->unsignedInteger('quiz_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

here table 2

```
<?php

Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedInteger('question_id');
    $table->string('answer');
    $table->boolean('is_correct');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('answers', function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

what should I change in this code? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of [Laravel 5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade) `$table->id()` is an alias of `$table->bigIncrements('id')` which sets the `id` column's data type to unsigned `BIGINT` under the hood.

In the `answers` table, you've `$table->unsignedInteger('question_id');` which is equivalent to unsigned `INT`/`INTEGER` data type and that is not compatible with what `$table->id()` represents in the `questions` table. So you have to change the data type of `question_id` column to unsigned `BIGINT` in the `answers` table.

And to do that, you need to use `Blueprint::unsignedBigInteger()` method to make the `question_id` column's data type unsigned `BIGINT` as you're setting it up as a foreign key.

**So use**

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('question_id');
```

Instead of

```
$table->unsignedInteger('question_id');
```

Comment: @FebriTahta do NOT forget to mark the answer correct that helped you here. :)

Comment: yes sir.. thanks for ur answer, i got typo in my command before, im deleted. im already mark this answer correct. :) thankyou

Answer (score 1):

> Be Careful: Laravel 5.8 Added bigInteger for foreign key ( As Defaults)

In your foreign key column do `bigInteger()` instead of `integer()`.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('question_id');
```

Comment: thanks sir now im understand :)

Answer (score 1):

`$table->id();` is alias of `$table->bigIncrements('id')` so you should use `$table->unsignedBigInteger('question_id');`

Comment: thanks for ur answer sir